# Which library should import to use Liferay.ThemeDisplay in Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, liferay

Hello everyone i’m trying to run this code on my react application but it doesn’t work because ‘Liferay’ is not defined. I’ve already tried to import alloyUi library but it doesn’t work, so what should i do to fix it? Thanks.

Simply the code:

```
if(Liferay.ThemeDisplay.isSignedIn()){
    alert('Hello ' +          Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getUserName() + '. Welcome Back.')
}
else {
    alert('Hello Guest.')
}
```

Should i import a specific library?

Comment: Could you be running this code in index.js before the Liferay JS has had a chance to load? Or is it from like an event handler? Component? You also say `I’ve already tried to import alloyUi library` - does it actually load before this code runs? Also importing how? Can you run Liferay.something in your devtools console?

Comment: I tried to run it also in index.js but same problem, but I still need it in a component. I've installed the library with command 'npm i alloy-ui' that I found on npmjs.com

Comment: but when I try to import Liferay from 'alloy-ui' I have 'module not installed'.

Comment: I think the issue is with your workflow. If you use `npm i` that sounds like you are using npm to work with react too; is that right? If you forget about react for now, can you run just `alert(123)` from your portlet? If that works, does `console.log(Liferay)`? You need to get those two working before you would even think about React. Or alternatively, are you thinking of creating a pure frontend app with something like `create-react-app` and just using Liferay as a backend via the APIs? That would be a completely way of working that requires a very different approach

Comment: I finally imported the right library I guess, it's liferay-portal7.4; but now when I try to access to Liferay.ThemeDisplay.isSignedIn() I get undefined is not an object, that's why if I try to console.log(Liferay.ThemeDisplay) I have undefined. The library is not the right one or there is something to do to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I'll leave that up to those who has worked with Liferay more lately (it's been 5 or so years for me) but it's quite difficult to try and imagine exactly what is going on without actually seeing any of your code.